# Subversion everybody can checkout

Tags: linux, svn, debian

I setup a debian based server and installed subversion on it. After I configured the subversion client I did my first checkout. But I recognized a problem.

When I am using the svn protocol I can do a checkout without entering a username or password. But when I am using the http:// protocol I need to enter a username and password.

Now I want that I only can do a checkout when I have a correct username and password. Whatever which protocol I use.

In the /etc/apache2/ dir I created a .passwd file which is working and an .authz file.

> > **In the .authz file I have**

```
[groups]
developer = name

[/]
@developer = rw
* =
```

**in my dav_svn.conf :**

```
<Location /project1>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /var/svn/project1

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "bla"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn.project1.passwd
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn.project1.authz
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: An (older) tutorial on setting up access control through the `svn` protocol can be found on [Ubuntu's Server Guide](http://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/subversion.html) and all the details are in the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth).

Answer (score 1):

Add a

```
Satisfy Any
```

Directive before the

```
Required valid-user
```

Correct it should be:

```
<Location /project1>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /var/svn/project1

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "bla"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/svn.project1.passwd
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn.project1.authz
    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Ok thx for your response! I figured out my problem:

In the file /var/svn/project1 I simply had to add anon-access: none